# JDBC MySQL logstash convert to float

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Hi everyone I have a problem using logstash currently i'm importing from mysql using JDBC plugin but when I have float field those are converted as string throwing following error:

@metadata_accessors=#, @cancelled=false>], :response=>{"create"=>{"_index"=>"mobtrack_events_2016.06.01", "_type"=>"event", "_id"=>"AVVVrlZX6r2RMu2ES09Q", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [sell.price]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"number_format_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: \"0.49000000953674316\""}}}}, :level=>:warn}

I'm using `convert => ["sell.price", "float]` but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem updating to logstash 2.3.2.